# mqtt broker - aclfile

Tags: debian, mqtt, mosquitto, broker

I installed mosquitto on Debian 9

```
apt-get install mosquitto mosquitto-clients
```

did a Re-Start
    service mosquitto restart

tested it

```
mosquitto_pub -d -t My/Topic2 -m "Hello MQTT"
```

no error message

created a password

```
mosquitto_passwd -c /etc/mosquitto/passwd myUsername
```

created a aclfile

```
touch /etc/mosquitto/aclfile
nano /etc/mosquitto/aclfile
```

with this content:

```
# This affects access control for clients with no username.
topic read myTopic/#

# This only affects clients with username "myUsername".
user myUsername
topic myTopic/#

# This affects all clients.
pattern write $SYS/broker/connection/%c/state
```

insert the path to the acl_file to this file

```
nano /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

acl_file /etc/mosquitto/aclfile
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
```

so the plan is that user "myUsername" can publish in "myTopic" and all other user including guests can only read.

I had this configuration already running on an other server but in this case something is wrong
The 1st time I tested I forgot to add the password_file path to the mosquitto.conf 
and got the Error: Connection refused if I want so publish
also if I want only to subscribe

OK I fixed this problem but now I can publish without username / password

and of corse I did the restart:

```
service mosquitto restart
```

So if I send

```
mosquitto_pub -d -t myTopic/test -m "Access denied is expected"
```

I get no error, looks like the messange is published

if I open a second shell (and also from a remote machine)
I can subscribe

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t myTopic/test
```

but if I publish something to this topic nothing is received (Ping is working)

Any ideas for my 2 problems ?

PS: I am NO Linux professional
so if you want more information please provide me with the correct information how to get this information

EDIT: if I use

```
ps -efc
```

this is the only entry with mosquitto

```
mosquit+ 736 1 TS 19 21:36 ? 00:00:02 /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

in the log

```
nano /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
```

I get

```
ACL denying access to client with dangerous client id "mosqpub/7977-Debian-93-"
ACL denying access to client with dangerous client id "mosqpub/356-h2700629"
```

but regarding google this should be already fixed last year

I am using mosquitto version 1.4.10

Comment: Check that mosquitto is actually using the config file you have provided. (The logs should list the path conf file being used on the 2nd line at start up, or it should be listed in the output of `ps -efc`). Mosquitto does not use a config file unless explicitly told to.

Comment: if I use ps -efc this is the only entry with mosquitto

mosquit+   736     1 TS   19 21:36 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

is this correct ?

Comment: Edit the question to include updated information. But yes it looks like it is using the config file. So you need to check the log file (the location of which should be in the conf file). If it shows nothing obvious then you may want to turn the logging level up (see the man page for mosquitto.conf and the `log_type` option)

Comment: in the log

    nano /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

I get

    ACL denying access to client with dangerous client id "mosqpub/7977-Debian-93-"
    ACL denying access to client with dangerous client id "mosqpub/356-h2700629"

but regarding google this should be already fixed last year

Comment: It may have been fixed but we have no idea what version of mosquitto you are actually running.

Comment: I just installed it today so I assume it is the latest, regarding the log: mosquitto version 1.4.10

Comment: 1.4.10 was released August 2016. The latest version is 1.4.14 (July 2017)

Comment: In the log it says:
mosquitto version 1.4.10 (build date Mon, 29 May 2017 13:43:29 +0100) starting
however its older than 1.4.14 and no chance to update it via "apt-get" :/

mosquitto_sub -d -i test123 -t  myTopic/test

also doesnt work if I want to use a manuel client id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user is not allowed to publish to a topic the publish will just silently fail. This is working as designed for MQTT (at least at MQTT v3.x).

You also probably need to add the `allow_anonymous false` if you want to prevent clients that do not pass a username/password.

To get the latest version of mosquitto, follow the instructions on https://mosquitto.org/download/ to install the correct ppa

Comment: the plan is that user "myUsername" can publish in "myTopic" and all other user including guests can only read, due to this allow_anonymous is set to true. If I send with the -i parameter the error messages in the log disappear. How ever you are right, if I insert "-u username -P password" than it works, I was expecting an access denied message :) Sorry I can not vote your answer, to less points :(

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue and found out that it was about the `/` in the username/client-id. From https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/5c45bc4e8407d94d29b39152b580d2b4cc8082e9/src/security.c#L609-L610:

```
/* Check whether the client id or username contains a +, # or / and if
 * so deny access.
```

Removing the '/' made it work again.